# What's the reason for WordPress plugin_url() function?

Tags: wordpress

I'm learning about WordPress plugins.
I am struggling to understand the purpose of the existence of a separate
`plugin_url()` function to get the absolute path to a plugin as opposed to
a generic function that gets the absolute path to a file to be used as a
more generic one in place of `plugin_url()`.

Suppose I have a script.js in my `wp-content/plugins/myplugin` directory.

Why do a

```
$src = plugin_url('script.js', __FILE__)
```

instead of simply

```
$src = dirname(__FILE__) . "/" . 'script.js'
```

Furthermore, why is it necessary to use absolute URLs in `wp_register_script()`?
Can local URLs be used? Are relative paths deprecated or something?

Comment: Would your example of `dirname(__FILE__) . "/" . 'script.js'` really do the same job? Wouldn't that return you a filesysstem path rather than a URL?

Comment: Searching the core files, I can't find a function `plugin_url()`, only [**`plugins_url()`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2061). If you read the function's description and code, you'll understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function helps with Wordpress MU by extending the path in the correct way per individual blog. Rather than open a page on a blog and the header uses paths, to .css or .js files, that do not match the current blogs path 100%.